# Mapping/plotting distance of values in 1 dimensional array/ series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas series which goes something like this:

```
(['StartGame', 'TutorialEnded',  'FBConnect',
  'StartGame', 'Sale', 'FBConnect', 'InviteSent',
  'StartGame', 'Finish_1', 'Sale', 'Bought',
  'Finish_22',  'FBConnect', 'Finish_2',
  'TutorialEnded', 'Finish_18', ...])
```

I would like to plot the distance between values that contain the string `Finish` and the appearance of the value `sale` to see if there is any correlation between the two, as well as check correlation between the appearence of other words in relation to `sale`. In other word, can I use the appearence of any values in my series to predict the occurence of `sale` nearby? Even to plot a scatter line where I assign each value a different color so I can get a feel for it would be helpful, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, whats happen? Why you delete your nice [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503142/regular-expression-matching-in-pandas-data-frame-column)? I hope I give you nice answer, it doesnt work? I am very surprised.

Comment: @jezrael oh sorry about that, I made a small spelling mistake, with the double equal signs. When I fixed it , it worked quite nicely. would you like me to re post it so you can answer something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['StartGame', 'TutorialEnded',  'FBConnect',
  'StartGame', 'Sale', 'FBConnect', 'InviteSent',
  'StartGame', 'Finish_1', 'Sale', 'Bought',
  'Finish_22',  'FBConnect', 'Finish_2',
  'TutorialEnded', 'Finish_18'], columns=['Value'])
df.index.name = 'position'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

#### Helper functions

```
def isFinish(x):
    """Returns True if Value matches 'Finish', False otherwise."""
    return bool(re.match(r'.*Finish.*', x.ix['Value']))

def isSale(x):
    """Returns True if Value matches 'Sale', False otherwise."""
    return bool(re.match(r'.*Sale.*', x.ix['Value']))

df['Finish'] = df.apply(isFinish, axis=1)
df['Sale'] = df.apply(isSale, axis=1)
df['FinishCount'] = df.Finish.cumsum()

def cumargmax(x):
    """get latest position of a Finish row."""
    if x.ix['FinishCount'] == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df.FinishCount.loc[:x.ix['position']].argmax()

df['Distance'] = df.position - df.apply(cumargmax, axis=1)
```

#### Demonstration

```
print df

    position          Value Finish   Sale  FinishCount  Distance
0          0      StartGame  False  False            0       NaN
1          1  TutorialEnded  False  False            0       NaN
2          2      FBConnect  False  False            0       NaN
3          3      StartGame  False  False            0       NaN
4          4           Sale  False   True            0       NaN
5          5      FBConnect  False  False            0       NaN
6          6     InviteSent  False  False            0       NaN
7          7      StartGame  False  False            0       NaN
8          8       Finish_1   True  False            1       0.0
9          9           Sale  False   True            1       1.0
10        10         Bought  False  False            1       2.0
11        11      Finish_22   True  False            2       0.0
12        12      FBConnect  False  False            2       1.0
13        13       Finish_2   True  False            3       0.0
14        14  TutorialEnded  False  False            3       1.0
15        15      Finish_18   True  False            4       0.0
```

Or subsetted by when there was a sale

```
print df[df.Sale]

   position Value Finish  Sale  FinishCount  Distance
4         4  Sale  False  True            0       NaN
9         9  Sale  False  True            1       1.0
```

Comment: @NANA If you are using a larger list than what you initially provided, please provide that as I'm sure the 'str' error is being generated because of some nuance in that data.  I've provided all the code you'd need.  Try to copy and paste my code and see if that works first.  If it does, then we can eliminate version issues.  The next step is to provide more of the traceback than just the small amount you have.

Comment: @NANA the KeyError is coming from you trying to execute my code on your dataframe when I explicitly specified a 'Value' column in the Setup section.  You probably don't have a column named 'Value'.  Set up your dataframe such that it does.

Comment: Yup you're right about everything, this worked very nicely. Thanks again.